# Powershell - Who activated a User

Tags: powershell

I'm a beginner in Powershell and I would like to create a script to check who activated a specific user in our AD.

So far, I have this:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -ComputerName ad.root| Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 4722} | Select-Object -Property *
```

First of all, is this right? It checks all the activated users in the ad.root domain.
Second...How can I search for a specific user a display it?

I tried the select-object parameter, but it don't work.

Comment: You're looking for the right type of event, but your command only checks the logs currently existing _on the particular domain controller you're talking to_. You'll need to collect your event logs to some central log store if you want full visibility here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4722 is the right event to search for. But I advise to use get-winevent instead of get-eventlog. By doing so you have the far better filter options (xpath) and it is faster.

But first you must ensure that those events are being logged. In the GPO valid to Domain Controllers ensure that the following option is active:

Advanced Audit Policy Configuration -> Account Management -> Audit User Account Management = Success

Furthermore as Mathias already has pointed out you need to check the logs of all Domain Controllers. You can achieve this by forwarding the events to central store by using event log forwarding or by using a 3rd party product like splunk or elastic. But for sure you can also check for those events by only using PowerShell.

Back to your example, to filter the log for eventid 4722 for a specific user account by using get-eventlog:

```
$username = "user123"
get-eventlog -LogName security | ?{$_.eventid -eq 4722 -and $_.message -match $username}
```